# Is there any shortcut key for visual studio programming?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I always found myself rolling the mouse wheel when programming for my project in visual studio 2013. I always need to look through my program code like at line 23 and then modify the code at line 220 and keep forth and backward. It get my eyes tired easily. Is there any tricks to help me save some reference points?

Comment: it;s called a bookmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the upper right corner of your code window there is a little arrow type icon which you can drag down to allow viewing of 2 different areas of the same window/tab. Very helpful when you are needing to go up and down in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

Menu Window -> Split

Or as said Yosem above you can use arrow at corner of code window.

UPD. Also you can make a bookmarks for any lines you want. It's in menu Edit -> Bookmarks -> Toggle bookmark (by default shortcut is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>). Then you can easily go to next/previous bookmark by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> / <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. It is helpful.